# I can't introduce the preferencescreen layout. I want to know why？

Tags: android, layout

My SDK version uses 33.
The "preferencescreen" of this code will turn red.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Why is that?I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You are using SDK 33, but the PreferenceScreen was deprecated in version 29.

According to the [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/package-summary.html) the Androidx PreferenceScreen is the newer way. You can implement it like :

```
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

instead of

```
<PreferenceScreen 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: I found the reason. The file must be placed in the XML folder.But thank you for your answer.